# How to make a compatible scrollable table with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need the header to be fixed in the below table.

```
<thead>
    <tr >

<td>tjj</td>
    <td>Marketing Phjgjgh </td>
<td>Mhjgjg Program Description </td>
    <td>Markjghjghgram type </td>
<td>CRM CjgjgjFlag </td>
<td>Brajghjjative </td>
<td>Marketijhgjhm Brand </td>
<td>Acjhgjting Program </td>

<td>CRMjgjhype</td>
    <td>Sweejghjhkes</td>
<td>Oldgjjgjivity Bypass</td>

</tr>
</thead>


    <tbody>
    <tr class="alternate1">
<td align="center"></td>
<td>EShjgjARDI</td>
<td>eShojghjmports</td>
<td>4 - Datajgjgjg or gjghjCapture</td>
<td>Y</td>
<td>38 jgjhards</td>
<td>00 jghjhporate</td>
<td>jh</td>
<td>jh</td>
<td>jgh</td>
<td>ghjhg</td>
</tr>

---SNIP-just more rows---
```

I've tried many solutions, but they only work on some browsers. For example,

```css
thead tr{
position:relative;
top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop);
}
```

and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9">` makes it work in only IE. The two-table concept does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [`jQgrid`](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)?  I highly recommend it.  It works in every browser I have ever tried and adds significant functionality.

If you don't want to do that, you may want to take their rendered approach.  They have a table for the header and another for the body.  The biggest hurdle with this approach is getting the columns to match width, but their approach works well and you can make the full result resize as needed.

You can see it in action [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Comment: not familiar with the concept .. kinda newebie   .... any methods using jquery js and css???

Comment: jQgrid uses jquery and you use css to skin it.

Comment: I highlighted the link in my response.  You can download and deploy it for free.

Comment: Did you try jqgrid? How did it work? If it worked, don't forget to check the answer so others know how it was solved.

Comment: no not yet ... as for nw its working in IE. i'll try it very soon n mark it correct as sun as i do